# Is there an API for NOAA GOES 15 satellite data?

Tags: api, netcdf, satellite, noaa

In August 2015, I was requesting GOES 15 GVAR_IMG satellite data because it had both visible and infrared light info (useful for studying cloud coverage and solar radiation).  I remember having to make email requests for the netCDF data and was wondering if something had changed.  Also, if I am just looking for visible light data this time around, is there an API that I could use to access NOAA satellite imagery?

Comment: Is this the information that you are after: https://satdat.ngdc.noaa.gov/sem/goes/data/full/

Comment: Thanks! I think I am looking specifically for GVAR_IMG data unless one of those instruments on the link that you provided has visible light capabilities.